# Web app hosted on iis 6 can't connect to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-6

I have an MVC4 web application hosted on IIS6.  Whenever I try to access it, I always get the error cannot connect to database.  In my test server running IIS 7.5, I create a user that own the database, then I add that user to the default app pool.  How is it done in IIS 6? I can't find the default app pool in the SQL Server Logins.

Comment: Do you have the proper credentials in your connection string to access the db ? I feel that this has nothing to do with IIS version.

Comment: @Shyju Yes, turns out it was a connection string problem.  Thanks.